# Extract function from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

In a nutshell, I have 3 divs that will have their bg colour randomly changed when clicked. They can only be clicked once, hence the `removeEventListener`. Am I just trying to over-complicate things?

I have 3 event listeners that all use the same function, but each with its own arguments:

```
doorLeft.addEventListener("click", function handler(ev) {
  randomChooseColour(doorLeft);
  ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, handler);
});

doorMiddle.addEventListener("click", function handler(ev) {
  randomChooseColour(doorMiddle);
  ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, handler);
});

doorRight.addEventListener("click", function handler(ev) {
  randomChooseColour(doorRight);
  ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, handler);
});
```

randomChooseColour is a basic function that takes one argument and changes that div background colour

```
const randomChooseColour = (door) => {
  if (randomSelect(2) === 0) {
    door.style.backgroundColor = winColour;
  } else {
    door.style.backgroundColor = loseColour;
  }
};
```

Is there any way to create that handler function outside the addEventListener? I tried to save it to a const and then use that const inside the eventListener, but it doesn't seem to work

```
const choose = function handler(ev, door) {
  randomChooseColour(door);
  ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, handler);
};
```

and then use it like this but **ev is not defined**.

```
doorLeft.addEventListener("click", choose(ev, doorLeft));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the body of the functions are different, I don't think there's a way to have a singe outside function that `removeEventListener` can be called for. But there is an easy way to simplify things: use `{ once: true }` so that the listener can only be called once, no need for `removeEventListener` at all.

```
// the below line can be made less repetitive
// by using querySelectorAll instead, if possible
for (const door of [doorLeft, doorMiddle, doorRight]) {
  door.addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => randomChooseColor(door),
    { once: true }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I'll give that a go

Comment: Well, that worked but now for some reason, the event is randomly triggered multiple times in the same location.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the `{ once: true }` third argument?